# Bookmarking the url with the search result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, search

Method:

```
onSearch(searchString) {
    if (this.props.history) {
      this.props.history.push(
        "/details?search=" + encodeURIComponent(searchString)
      );
    }
  }
```

Search Bar:

```
<Search
                  onKeyPress={(event) => {
                    if (event.key === "Enter") {
                      this.onSearch(event.target.value);
                    }
                  }}
                />
```

onSearch method opens this url: **http://localhost:3000/marketPlace/details?search=iphone** and surfacing all the results with "iphone". What I want is whenever user bookmark this url, he should fall back in the same page with the search result as **iphone** . I have no idea how to do this, can anyone help me with this

Comment: Are you saying that when you go to the url directly (by entering it into the browser URL bar and hitting enter i.e. making an http request) you want the app to display in the same state as if you navigated to this route using the onSearch method? This will depend on the setup of your application, but you may want to look at React Router https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start. You can use it to match the url of your app to a state and instruct the app to load a particular React Component based upon the contents of the url.

Comment: yes, user expects to land on the same page when this url is shared over chats or emails

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are writing a client side application and you do not need the search results to be server side rendered, React Router (npm `react-router-dom`) will enable you to recreate a particular state of your app, based upon the url requested.

You should be able to apply a router to your existing app by following the React Router documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Here is a very simple example of a router that is similar to your use case.

The example shows that:

- A request to `/` will render the "Homepage" component.
- A request to `/search?term=iphone` will render the "SearchResults" component and `this.searchTerm` will be equal to the string `iphone`.
- The `SearchResults` component parses the query string from the url and identifies the search term. In the example, this is just displayed to the end user, but you can use it to fetch your search results e.g. using `fetch()`.

[image: Illustration of example: homepage]
[image: Illustration of example: search page]

You can reproduce the example with two files:

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let queryString = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
    this.searchTerm = queryString.get('term');
  }

  render() {
    return <p>Search results page for term: { this.searchTerm }</p>;
  }
}

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>

        <Route path="/search" component={SearchResults} />

        <Route path="/">
          <p>Homepage</p>
        </Route>

      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```